# Sound does not play on one page but does on another

Tags: javascript, class, audio

**INTRO**

I have two pages with multiple divs that have the same class name "listtitle". When the user clicks on the div it makes a sound. One page is in the parent directory, the other in a subdirectory(1 level) and the jquery file reside in another subdirectory(1 level).

**SCRIPT**

```
var obj0 = document.createElement("audio");
    obj0.src ="../airslide2.mp3";
    obj0.volume = 0.2;
    obj0.autoPlay = false;
    obj0.preLoad = true;
    $(".listtitle").click(function() {
        obj0.play();
    });
```

**HTML SNIPPET FROM BOTH PAGES**

```
<div id="listbox1" class="listbox">
<div class="listtitle">
</div>
</div>
```

**QUESTION**

I call the same script on both pages with relative paths to the jquery file that are correct. Does anyone see or know what might prevent the script from working on page 2 when listtitle div is clicked?

**NOTE**

For testing purposes, I have eliminated all other jquery/javascript(except for the audio script) from page 2 to insure I'm not dealing with conflicting scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The Big Ahh Moment. While more experienced developer would have caught this, I'm leaving this post up for those like me.

While the relative paths to my jquery code was correct for both pages. Page 1 (parent directory) | Page 2 (subdirectory) - the obj0.src =../ was not correct for the parent page.

**The Confusion**

I thought the mp3 file had to be relative to the jquery script which if I was not creating an element would be correct. Since I was creating an element for each page, i.e., document.createElement("audio"); the relative path for the mp3 in the parent page would be different.

**The Solution**

I created a separate script for the parent directory page and removed ../ from the obj0.src.